How to compare two lists when one list is the same repeated in Excel 2016
I am currently working with a large a series of data sheets of various lengths (1500-15000 lines) that record training records for employees. The current system built by a previous employee has no automation and takes a very long time for the department that utilizes the sheet to update it. Since they have to go to each employee one by one to add the course.
What I am trying to do is automate the task of adding training courses to each employee on a given sheet. There is currently a 'course master list' on a separate sheet tied to the sheet listing employees by location/department.
The goal of the macro would be to iterate through the list by employee names and compare the training module ID (column B) under each employee against the 'master course list' (column B) and if the 'master course list' has a module that doesn't exist in the 'employee list' then the macro would add the new module in by creating a new line and adding the employees name and the module.
The sheet listing the employees is similar to the image below but they are upwards of 15k lines (this would be before the macro is ran):



Name
Module




Joe Smith
TM.001.A


Joe Smith
TM.001.B


Joe Smith
TM.001.C


Joe Smith
TM.002.A


Joe Smith
TM.002.B


Joe Smith
TM.003.A


Joe Smith
TM.004.A


Joe Smith
TM.115.A


Joe Smith
TM.115.B


Jane Anders
TM.001.A


Jane Anders
TM.001.B


Jane Anders
TM.001.C


Jane Anders
TM.002.A


Jane Anders
TM.002.B


Jane Anders
TM.003.A


Jane Anders
TM.004.A


Jane Anders
TM.115.A


Jane Anders
TM.115.B



With the training course list that is used for comparison looking similar to this image (these sheets are around 100 to 150 lines):



Module Series
Module ID




Room Sanitation
TM.001.A


Room Sanitation
TM.001.B


Room Sanitation
TM.001.C


Conveyor Basics
TM.002.A


Conveyor Basics
TM.002.B


Hot Room
TM.003.A


Hot Room
TM.003.B


Cold Room
TM.004.A


Packaging Basics
TM.115.A


Packaging Basics
TM.115.B



The employee training list after the macro is ran (new rows are in bold):



Name
Module




Joe Smith
TM.001.A


Joe Smith
TM.001.B


Joe Smith
TM.001.C


Joe Smith
TM.002.A


Joe Smith
TM.002.B


Joe Smith
TM.003.A


Joe Smith
TM.003.B


Joe Smith
TM.004.A


Joe Smith
TM.115.A


Joe Smith
TM.115.B


Jane Anders
TM.001.A


Jane Anders
TM.001.B


Jane Anders
TM.001.C


Jane Anders
TM.002.A


Jane Anders
TM.002.B


Jane Anders
TM.003.A


Jane Anders
TM.003.B


Jane Anders
TM.004.A


Jane Anders
TM.115.A


Jane Anders
TM.115.B



I currently have built a few short lines of code that iterates by name that I am using for a couple of other Subs but I don't know enough about VBA to implement what I'm currently looking to do.
The iterative loop looks like this:
Dim col As Range, curr As Range
Set col = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xldown))
Dim col_val As String
For Each curr In col
    If curr.Value = col_val Then
        do stuff
    Else
        col_val = curr.Value
    End If
Next

This currently iterates through the names one by one and stores the current working name. My thoughts would be, when the name changes a counter would be set, or reset, that would increment for comparing to the master course list as the main loop iterates and when a difference is encountered a new line would be added, and populated, to the employee list and the loop would continue on. The trick is that it would be comparing a very long list of repeated information to a short list, and the difference is the employee name.
A couple of small notes: I don't plan on building this in a way that would iterate through multiple sheets in the book as the Master Course Lists are updated irregularly and individually. So this macro would only be ran by page as needed. I am also interested in doing what is possible to reduce processing time since this is all ran on VMs that utilize Excel 2016. My experience is heavy in C++ and Python with quite a few other languages, but this is my first time with VBA. Also this is only a temporary fix until I can get a more efficient solution built that doesn't require the amount of work that this system currently requires.
Thanks in advance for any advice and help provided.
Edit: Changed out images for MD tables, changed verbiage.

What do you mean by "a 'course master list' tied to each page of employees"? Is the data related to employee name on columns A:B? If not, in which columns is it? Then, should we understand that "tied to each page of employees" means existing in the same sheet? If so, on which columns? If not, based on what to make the matching? Supposing that my above assumptions are correct, or they will be clarified, how/where do you need the code to return? I think it would be good to edit your question and show the necessary data on the page (even a picture) and then the desired result.

It would be good to show at least two different names, courses etc. Since the processing logic is not so clear described (at least for me...) we will maybe better understand what you try doing looking to what you have and what you need...

@FaneDuru I edited the post with some mock up cells for better visual, and more clearly explained that the 'master course list' is on its own page separate from the list of employees. So the comparison will be between columns on different pages. I had to do mock ups since I only have access to the sheets through the VM and cannot access this site on the VM.
As for processing, the system that I have at my disposal has limited memory, and even just iterating through the names and hiding successive lines with the same employee name can take upwards of 10 min to run.

TM.003.B is not in training course list. Why it is added in output?
Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

@taller i fixed the images. i didnt realize I forgot the change the training course list

If you could share your data as MD table, it is helpful for SO users to test the script.

@taller changed them over

Is it possible that the module in the employee training list does not exist in the training course list?

@taller in the example above the first table is the employee training list before and the third table is the after. The second table is the training course list or master course list your answer is working 99% as I was looking for. theres a bunch that I need to do to make it work for the data set but it gets me in the right direction.

@taller but yes TM.003.B wouldn't be included in the the first employee training list

My last question is that the module in the employee training list does not exist in the training course list. eg. Joe Smith TM.999.B, but TM.999.B is not in training course list. If it never appears, then the solution will be straightforward.

@taller ok i understand, the intent is to go one direction, ideally only the training course list would get updated manually and the macro would update the employee training list

Using a nested Dict to store the employee training information
Microsoft documentation:

Range.Resize property (Excel)


Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngCell As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey
    Dim arrData, arrRes, iR As Long
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("MasterCourseList")  ' modify as needed
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("TrainingList")  ' modify as needed
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' load training list to Dict object
    arrData = oSht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    Set rngCell = oSht2.Cells(UBound(arrData) + 1, 1)
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1) ' employee name as key
        If Not objDic.exists(sKey) Then ' create nested Dict
            Set objDic(sKey) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        End If
        ' add modules for employee
        objDic(sKey).Add arrData(i, 2), Empty
    Next i
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1)
    arrData = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ' loop through master course list
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        ' loop through all employee
        For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
            If Not objDic(sKey).exists(arrData(i, 2)) Then
                ' add new row
                iR = iR + 1
                arrRes(iR, 0) = sKey
                arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 2)
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    If iR = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing changed"
    Else
        ' write output to sheet
        rngCell.Resize(iR, 2) = arrRes
        MsgBox iR & " rows are added to " & oSht2.Name
    End If
End Sub



If the module in the employee training list always exists in the training course list without any exceptions, then the following snippet is a more straightforward approach.
Sub Demo2()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngCell As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey
    Dim arrData1, arrData2, arrRes, iR As Long
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet, oSht3 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("MasterCourseList")  ' modify as needed
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("TrainingList")  ' modify as needed
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' load training list to Dict object
    arrData2 = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData2) + 1 To UBound(arrData2)
        sKey = arrData2(i, 1) ' employee name as key
        If Not objDic.exists(sKey) Then ' create nested Dict
            objDic(sKey) = Empty
        End If
    Next i
    arrData1 = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData1) * UBound(arrData2), 1)
    ' loop through master course list
    For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
        For i = LBound(arrData1) + 1 To UBound(arrData1)
            ' loop through all employee
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 0) = sKey
            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData1(i, 2)
        Next i
    Next
    If iR = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing changed"
    Else
        Set oSht3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        oSht3.Name = "NewList"
        oSht3.Range("A1:B1").Value = oSht1.Range("A1:B1").Value
        oSht3.Range("A2").Resize(iR, 2) = arrRes
    End If
End Sub


@AbyssalPlatypus Have tried my code?

I'm getting it set up now, it took longer to get back to this than expected

got it implemented, but the output is different, its inserting the lines at the end.

I've updated the snippet.

Please, test the next code, too. It also uses a dictionary and arrays. It should be very fast, processing almost everything in memory.
Now, it returns in column D:D of the employee sheet. If not empty, adapt the code to return wherever you have available place. If the return is convenient you should change the last code line to return in "A1" (wsEmp.Range("D2") -> wsEmp.Range("A2"))
Sub UpdateCourses()
 Dim wsEmp As Worksheet, wsTr As Worksheet, arrTr, arrEmp, arrIt, arrFin
 Dim mtch, i As Long, j As Long, dict As Object
 
 Set wsEmp = ActiveSheet 'use here the correct sheet
 Set wsTr = Worksheets("Sheet(168)")
 
 arrTr = wsTr.Range("B2", wsTr.Range("B" & wsTr.rows.count).End(xlUp)).Value  'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 arrEmp = wsEmp.Range("A2", wsEmp.Range("B" & wsEmp.rows.count).End(xlUp)).Value
 
 'load the dictionary:
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrEmp)
    If Not dict.Exists(arrEmp(i, 1)) Then
        dict.Add arrEmp(i, 1), Array(arrEmp(i, 2))
    Else
        arrIt = dict(arrEmp(i, 1)) 'place the item array in an outer array
                                   'in a dictionary you can change the item directly
                                   'but except an array...
        ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1) 'ReDim the array to make place for a new last element
        arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = arrEmp(i, 2)     'load the next course in the item array
        dict(arrEmp(i, 1)) = arrIt              'place back the updated array
    End If
 Next i
 
 'match existing courses and add the not matching ones:
 For j = 0 To dict.count - 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrTr)
       mtch = Application.match(arrTr(i, 1), dict.Items()(j), 0)
       If IsError(mtch) Then 'if it does not exists
            arrIt = dict.Items()(j)
            ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1)
            arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = arrTr(i, 1) 'load the not existing course in the item array
            dict(dict.keys()(j)) = arrIt       'place back the updated array
       End If
    Next i
 Next j
 
 'determine the necessary rows of the final array (arrFin) to be processed including the new coourses:
 Dim countC As Long, k As Long
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    countC = countC + UBound(dict.Items()(i)) + 1
 Next i
 
 'redim arrFin (2D array):
 ReDim arrFin(1 To countC, 1 To 2)
 
 'Load in the array the necessary data:
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    For j = 0 To UBound(dict.Items()(i))
        k = k + 1
        arrFin(k, 1) = dict.keys()(i)     'place the dictionary key in the array first row
        arrFin(k, 2) = dict.Items()(i)(j) 'place each course from the dictionary item array in the array second row
    Next
 Next i
 
 'drop the final array content at once:
 wsEmp.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value = arrFin 'Attention!
                                                            'it drop the result in "D2". If D:D is not empty
                                                            'choose another column. If the return is convenient
                                                            'you can change "D2" with "A2" to overwrite...
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

